# How do I set clickListener to drawer items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener, drawerlayout

I've this drawer layout working as navigation drawer. How can I set the item click listener to the items inside it. As for example I have Home, Maps and About in my drawer layout and I want to open new fragment on each item click.

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ScrimInsetsFrameLayout mScrimInsetsFrameLayout;

private void init_navigator(){
    // Navigation Drawer
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);
    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
    mScrimInsetsFrameLayout = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_navigation_drawer_rootLayout);

    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
            (
                    this,
                    mDrawerLayout,
                    toolbar,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_opened,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_closed
            )
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
        {
            // Disables the burger/arrow animation by default
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // Navigation Drawer layout width
    int possibleMinDrawerWidth = UtilsDevice.getScreenWidth(this) -
            UtilsMiscellaneous.getThemeAttributeDimensionSize(this, android.R.attr.actionBarSize);
    int maxDrawerWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.navigation_drawer_max_width);

    mScrimInsetsFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().width = Math.min(possibleMinDrawerWidth, maxDrawerWidth);
    // Set the first item as selected for the first time
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title_home);


}
```

Comment: use RecyclerView in Drawer item

Comment: Don't you have navigationview for drawer in xml?

Comment: no, i don't have navigation view.

Comment: Find tutorial for NavigationDrawer that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id  = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_dashboard:
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_maps:
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_user_management:
            return  true;
        case R.id.nav_view:
            return true;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And try the navigation drawer activity when creating a new project to get a better navigation drawer.